# Logistic Regression Multiple Models

Tags: regression, logistic

If you have a population size of 61,000 and you take a sample of 10,000 should you run your model with different random samples to gain better results?
I ran a logistic regression model twice both with different random samples.[image: two random samples]
Both Models had the same AIC and SC values as well as very similar c statistic values (.773 and .771 respectively)
In the first sample, the p values are a lot less than .05.  On the second random sample the p values for some variables (employer name, preferred adr line 1) are close to .05.  Would it be better to use the first model since the p values are much lower?

Comment: These models seem to have different independent variables and also do not appear to be nested, making this like comparing apples and oranges. Also, you have not provided any information on what you are trying to model. Simply focusing on p values is generally not a good way to model data.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Both models have the same independent variables. I simply blocked out the ones that weren't statistically significant in either model. 
I am trying to model what factors contribute to the odds a Donor of a university will donate.  In the first model it shows that if someone has a professional suffix they are 8 times more likely to donate than if someone does not have a professional suffix but in the second model it shows that it is only 2.5 times more likely.

Comment: Another question. Why are you drawing two random samples of 10,000? By doing so, you are not using over 40,000 cases. If you want a validation sample, then split the sample into a testing and validation sample and then compare those models but don't focus on statistical significance. Rather, focus on the size and direction of the coefficients (or odds ratios).

Comment: My total dataset (population) is 61,000 alumni.  37% have donated ad 63% have not.  I split up my sample into 3,700 donors and 6,300 non donors which equals my 10,000 sample.  I ran the first model then went back to my population and pulled another 10,000 sample to see if the result would be the same.  So I should split the 10,000 into 5,000 testing and 5,000 validation?

Comment: Okay, I understand what you did but I fail to see why you did it. Do you have a reason for not running your model on the entire 61,000 alumni?

Comment: I thought that a random sample would help with any outliers. Is this pointless? Should I just run it on the total alumni base?

Comment: That is not an effective way of dealing with outliers. Do you have any? Also, with 61,000 cases, an outlier would need to be very extreme to have any real effect and likely would indicate an error in the data. You should check all of your variables to make sure that they have only valid values.  With such a large data set, you have many options but I see no reason not use run the model on the full data set. Just remember that with such a big sample size, almost everything will be significant so focus on size of effects more than p-values.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help! I ran it against all cases and came out with odds ratios of 3.6, 3.3, 2.6, 1.9, 1.4 then slowly they go down to .3. Should I focus just on the four highest ones?

Comment: Remember that an odds-ratio of 1 is the "no effect" odds ratio. An odds ratio of .3 is just as big as an odds ratio of 3.33 (1/.3). I can't really make this decision for you as it is not really statistical but conceptual and theoretical. How big of an effect (odds ratio) must be to be meaningful depends on context, including what purpose you have in mind for using the results.  That said, anything near 1 is unlikely to be very meaningful in explaining the likelihood of someone donating to the university.

Comment: Perfect. Makes total sense. Thank you very much for your help!